# How to write a code to calculate and display the stuffing / padding byte

Tags: c++, class, padding

See the below code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class temp
{
    public:
        int x;  //8
        char z; //4
        int y;
};

int main()
{
    temp tmp;

    cout << "Total size=" << sizeof(tmp) << endl;
    cout << "x=" << sizeof(tmp.x) /*<< "y" << sizeof(tmp.y) */<< "z=" << sizeof(tmp.z) << endl;
    return 0;
}


Output comes:
Total size: 12
x=4 y=4 z=1
```

My question is: for different data types, stuffing / padding bytes will be placed. However how can we identify and calculate the total size of stuffing/padding bytes or how can we write code (generally not specific to this code) ?

Comment: You might want to read about [`offsetof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof).

Comment: Why do you need to know about the total amount of padding bytes?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I tried via offsetof:                                                               std::cout << offsetof(temp, x);
    std::cout << offsetof(temp, y);
    std::cout << offsetof(temp, z);                                              Output: 0 8 4.. Can you please explain me how it's calculating like this.. I just want how the padding byte is inserted between data types

Comment: @hims what was the problem with `offsetof`? Why didn't you show what you tried?

Comment: You can use #pragma packed to set the padding.

Comment: So if member `z` is at offset 4 and with size 1, and the next member is at offset 8, then what would the padding be?